# Issues passing JSON value through prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, null, segue, sender

I have a simple app which connects to a web server and the web server returns a JSON value.

I am trying to send the JSON value from ViewController1 to "linkController", however when I send the sender over to ViewController2 the sender value is null?

Here is my code:

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"linkControllerSegue"]) {
        linkController *lc = [segue destinationViewController];
        lc.introString =  sender;

    }
}
```

This is part of my linkController.h file:

```
    @interface linkController : UIViewController
{
    // succes view outlets
    IBOutlet UILabel *short_url;
    IBOutlet UILabel *full_url;
    UIDataDetectorTypes *json;


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDictionary *introString;
```

And my linkController.m file:

```
@synthesize introString;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"%@", introString);
}
```

The segue is being called through the code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"linkControllerSegue" sender:nil];
```

The NSLog in the viewDidLoad method returns: (null).

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks,

Peter

Comment: How are you calling the Segue? Via code or via the Storyboard?

Comment: Code, check my update

Comment: @PeterStuart Are you pressing a UIButton to segue?

Comment: I press a button, it calls a few methods, then calls the segue

Comment: The segue is not connected to the button however. @AbdullahShafique

Comment: How can the log of sender return a JSON array when you're passing nil as the sender argument in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:? That doesn't make sense. Also, you say you're trying to pass a string, but you have introString typed as a dictionary. If you're passing a string, it should be typed as a string, and it should be strong, not weak.

Comment: The issue is your sender is nil so that is the reason in prepare for Segue that your sender there is also nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 lc.introString =  short_url.text;
```

instead of:

```
 lc.introString =  sender;
```

Comment: Still get the response null. Did you get my other comment? The button is not linked to the segue.

Comment: @PeterStuart Ok then when does the segue get called?

Comment: Inside a method. The segue is  The code that calls the segue is in the question :)

Comment: @PeterStuart Ok where is the data you want to pass (Labels text, NSString)

Comment: The data I want to pass is a JSON string. If I place NSLog(@"%@", sender); in the prepareForSegue the NSLog returns that JSON array.   If I attempt to pass it through to the other controller, the other controller returns it as a null value.

Comment: the short_url object is a different thing all together in the linkController (target controller)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40022/discussion-between-peter-stuart-and-abdullah-shafique)